# Translate objects in SVG using percentages

Tags: svg

I want to position one element in SVG using relative values (percentages of viewport) and after that rotate it.

This is my try to achive this:

```
<svg version="1.1"
  baseProfile="full"
  width="100%" height="100%"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs>
    <g id="corner">
      <path d="M 0 10000 L 0 0 L 10000 0" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use transform="translate(5 5)" xlink:href="#corner" />


  <!-- Nice try! Not works :) -->
  <g transform="translate(50% 50%)">
    <use transform="rotate(45)" xlink:href="#corner" />
  </g>


  <!-- Nice try! Not works too. Now viewpot/viewbox gets clipped :) -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" x="50%" y="50%">
    <use transform="rotate(45)" xlink:href="#corner" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

1. First method doesn't work for unknown reasons. Maybe translate doesn't accept percentages.
2. Second method moves and rotates object properly. But viewport gets clipped and I don't get desired result, because my object becomes invisible with clipping.

Comment: percentages are not allowed in viewBox attributes. If you don't want clipping overflow="visible" turns it off.

Answer (score 0):

This is code, that works in my case:

```
<svg version="1.1"
  baseProfile="full"
  width="100%" height="100%"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <g id="corner">
      <path d="M 0 10000 L 0 0 L 10000 0" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use transform="translate(5 5)" xlink:href="#corner" />

  <svg width="100%" height="100%" x="50%" y="50%" overflow="visible">
    <use transform="rotate(45)" xlink:href="#corner" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson

Comment: If you're going to credit me, fix the viewBox attribute to be valid too please.

Comment: @RobertLongson I can update code no problem. But when I remove 100% from viewBox, it stops do what I want it to do (fill all the area). You can check sample here under "Img with border on top": http://html.accuraten.com/doubleup-html/public/elements.html

Comment: Having percentages in the viewBox is invalid, it's the same, therefore as not having a viewBox at all.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you recommend any solution, that works the same and valid? Just dropping viewBox?

Comment: An invalid viewBox and no viewBox work the same so just drop it and the preserveAspectRatio too as that only has an effect if there's a valid viewBox attribute.